# VBA - Sort Range variable passed to a function

Tags: vba, sorting

I created a VBA UDF which receives a range selected by its users in an Excel spreadsheet. For example, *=MyFunction(A1:A5).*

**My question is:** Can I sort the values of the cells within this range without having to loop on each cell and then recreating the variable?

I tried the method below but it did not work:

```
MyVariableName.Sort 1, xlAscending
```

Thanks in advance,

Wendell

Comment: afaik an UDF cannot affect your worksheets cells directly (apart from the VALUE of its parent-cell, obviously), so I recon you cannot sort the values in `A1:A5` (neither with a `.sort` nor with a loop).

Comment: Hi Martin. I do not expect to physically sort the cells in the spreadsheet, I want to sort the values only in the passed range variable for later usage in the UDF code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming only one column is selected, you can put those values into an array and bubble sort the array.

```
Function MyUDF(rng as range)

Dim vals() as variant

redim vals(rng.rows.count - 1)

for each cell in rng
   vals(x) = cell.value
   x = x + 1
next cell

'your code

End Function
```

---

```
Sub BubbleSort(list() As Variant)

'   Sorts an array using bubble sort algorithm

Dim first As Integer, last As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim temp As Long

first = LBound(list)
last = UBound(list)
For i = first To last - 1
    For j = i + 1 To last
        If list(i) > list(j) Then
            temp = list(j)
            list(j) = list(i)
            list(i) = temp
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

The vals array will be sorted ascending.